Selenium Tests Failing on GitLab CI Runner (Windows) and Seeing White Screen in Headless Mode Locally
I'm encountering an issue with Selenium tests in a .NET/C# project using the NUnit framework, and I’m seeing two related issues between my local machine and the CI environment.
Setup and Issue Overview
The tests run smoothly on my local machine in both headed and headless modes. However, they consistently fail on the GitLab CI runner (Windows environment), in both headed and headless mode.
In addition to the CI runner failures, when I run these tests in headless mode locally, I also get a brief white screen that flashes between test cases. This doesn’t happen in headed mode, where everything works as expected.
Error on CI Runner
In the GitLab CI runner, I’m encountering a WebDriverTimeoutException, indicating that the tests are unable to locate an element with the selector .loading-indicator. Here’s the error message:
Failed GroupingMenu [1 m 4 s]
  Error Message:
   OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 60 seconds
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".loading\-indicator"}
  (Session info: chrome=129.0.6668.91)

The tests locate and interact with this element successfully on my local machine, but it fails to appear on the CI runner. Although I’ve tried capturing screenshots to debug this, I haven’t been able to access them due to a pipeline issue causing reports to disappear (I plan to address this separately).
Chrome Driver Configuration
Here's the ChromeOptions setup I’m currently using:
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--headless");  // Only used if headless mode is enabled
options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.AddArguments("test-type=browser");
options.AddArguments("--enable-automation");
options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Troubleshooting Steps Taken

Extended Timeout: Increased WebDriverWait timeout to 90 seconds to allow more time for the .loading-indicator to appear, but the element still wasn’t located.

Page Load Wait: Added a wait to ensure the page’s document readyState is "complete" before attempting to find the element:


driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
String readyState = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState");
log.Info("Ready State: " + readyState);


Headed Mode in CI: Ran the CI pipeline in headed mode on the GitLab runner, but the tests failed similarly, suggesting the issue might be specific to the CI environment rather than headless mode.

White Screen in Local Headless Mode: When running tests in headless mode on my local machine, I see a bright white screen flash briefly between test cases. The screen has no interactable window and disappears as soon as the next test starts. This issue doesn’t occur in headed mode.


My Hypothesis
I’m wondering if GitLab’s CI runner environment on Windows might be causing some rendering or timing issues. Perhaps the .loading-indicator element behaves differently on the CI runner due to network delays, environmental differences, or some aspect of Chrome’s headless handling on Windows.
Question
Has anyone experienced similar behaviour with Selenium on GitLab’s Windows runners? Or encountered the white screen flash in headless mode locally? I’d appreciate any suggestions, configurations, or debugging approaches to help resolve this.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
